# Need help creating dictionary from plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have the following format in my plist:

[image]

I'm using this code which works fine to pull all `muscleName` and set them as the table's cell's textLabel:

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableArray *rootLevel = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.muscleArray = rootLevel;
    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.muscleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"muscleName"];
```

But now I'm adding a search bar, and I want the results to show the `exerciseName` with corresponding `muscleName` and `musclePicture` keys.

I tried just doing `[[self.muscleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"exerciseName"];` but that doesn't fetch anything

Comment: Are you searching across all your muscles, or within one muscle dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[self.muscleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"exercises"]
```

Will give you an NSArray holding two dictionaries (from the data above), each dictionary holding a string for the key `exerciseName`. You can also do

```
[[[self.muscleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"exercises"] valueForKey:@"exerciseName"]
```

Which will return you an NSArray of NSStrings holding the two exercise names.

Your data isn't really laid out in a way that facilitates a nice search. You are trying to search within a dictionary contained within an array contained within a dictionary contained within an array!  It might be worth creating an alternate array for search purposes - that would be done something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayForSearching = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *muscleDict in self.muscleArray)
    for (NSDictionary *excerciseDict in [muscleDict objectForKey:@"exercises"])
        [arrayForSearching addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithValuesAndKeys:
            [exerciseDict objectForKey:@"exerciseName"],@"exerciseName",
            [muscleDict objectForKey:@"muscleName"],@"muscleName",nil]];
```

(typed in browser and untested, so please forgive any errors!)

Comment: Yes, I can create another array from the plist if necessary. All I want to do is create a universal search that searches exerciseName. But the cell should also have the myscleName as its detail text do I'll have to link that up as well.

Comment: Do you have any insight into creating a new array for searching purposes?

Comment: I'd go for an array of dictionaries, with exercise name and muscle name. You'll be repeating the muscle name over and over but it's only a string. You should be able to build this fairly easily by running through your existing array, let me know if you need any help with that.

Comment: Thanks!  So I'm thinking i need to do some type of enumerating to go through the array.  Would you be able to help set that up? Thanks!